# If a Cell is found twice in a column, paste contents of cell next to the cell found

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to write a macro with which I can check if in Column A there is any value multiple times. If there is a value twice I want the macro to copy the value of the cell next to the cell that is double and paste it, in the cell next to the original cell, divided by the contents of the cell it is pasted in with a ";". I know that sentence is quite complex but I find it hard to describe my problem.
[This is the worksheet not "damaged" by my macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHiRO.png)

The stuff I just described works more or less, the problem I have is that, if there is a cell with the same content multiple times, and the cell next to those also has the same value, the macro, logically, puts in the value multiple times as well. I don't really know how to stop that. Also, with my macro so far if a cell next to the cell that exists twice is empty, the macro  can result to putting many, unwanted, ";".

[This is after my macro "destroyed" the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKlmq.png)

I am still quite new to VBA and very greatful for any help that I can get!

Edit:
Here is what I came up with so far

```
Option Explicit

Sub Dopplungen()

Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, rcell As Range, rcell2 As Range, valueold As String, valuenew As String

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A2:A500")

For Each rcell In rng.Cells
    If rcell.Value <> vbNullString Then
        For Each rcell2 In rng.Cells
            If rcell.Value = rcell2.Value Then
                If rcell.Address <> rcell2.Address Then
                    valueold = rcell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    valuenew = rcell2.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    If rcell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> rcell2.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                        If rcell2.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
                            If rcell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
                            rcell.Offset(0, 1).Value = valueold & ";" & valuenew
                            Else
                            rcell.Offset(0, 1).Value = valuenew
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next rcell2
    End If
Next rcell
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the code you've written? Is the "not damaged" macro an example of the desirable result?

Comment: Could you add to the question the code that you've already written?

Comment: Also, please post a view of the worksheet with the result you would like to see/get.

Comment: Also please explain why retyping your original data is a good use of everyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one possibility is using `Dictionary` object, which has the property of having unique *keys*

like per this code (explanations in comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim fruitRng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("fruits") 'change "fruits" to your actual worksheet name
        Set fruitRng = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 'get its range in columns "A:B" from row 1 down to column A last not empty cell
    End With

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In fruitRng.Columns(1).Cells 'first loop to get unique fruit names and associate them a dictionary
            Set .Item(cell.Value) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Next

        For Each cell In fruitRng.Columns(1).Cells 'second loop to fill each fruit dictionary with its color
            If cell.Offset(, 1).Value <> "" Then 'mind only not empty color cells
                With .Item(cell.Value) 'reference the current fruit dictionary
                    .Item(cell.Offset(, 1).Value) = .Item(cell.Offset(, 1).Value) 'add current color in its keys, so you get a unique list of them
                End With
            End If
        Next

        For Each cell In fruitRng.Columns(1).Cells 'third loop to finally write down the colors next to each fruit
            cell.Offset(, 1).Value = Join(.Item(cell.Value).Keys, ";")
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You are such a great help!!! Thank you so much for taking all the time to answer my question and to write the code and comment it in such a detailed manner!!! Thank you so much!